# Respond to media keys in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Is it possible for a Silverlight application to respond to media keys like play/pause and volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those keys map to keyboard combinations (like Ctrl-Alt-P), then yes.
You can do a simple test to see if any keydown/keyup events are triggered when you press the buttons.
Michael

Comment: PlatformKeyCode indicates the key that was pressed even though the Key property is unknown.  Thanks!